# Cannot *create* Ionic app

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I just installed nodejs, ionic and cordova in OS X El capitan.

Now I was trying to follow the super simple "get started" tutorial on Ionic homepage to make sure my installation is OK.

See what I get:

`macmini:IONIC poko$ ionic start myApp tabs 
Creating Ionic app in folder /Users/poko/IONIC/myApp based on tabs project Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip [=============================]  100%  0.0s 
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip 
[=============================]  100%  0.0s 
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions 
Update Config.xml 
Initializing cordova project Adding in iOS application by default macmini:IONIC poko$ cd myApp/ 
macmini:myApp poko$ ionic build ios 
macmini:myApp poko$ ionic emulate ios 
macmini:myApp poko$`

When I enter `ionic build ios`, nothing happens. The terminal hangs for one second, then command prompt reappears. Same thing with `ionic emulate ios`.
No error messages nor error files are generated

What I did wrong??

Comment: I was recently having the same issue. Try updating you Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't see any Xcode update in the app store. Besides, what Xcode has to do with ionic and cordova?

Comment: (1/2) Good question, this was confusing for me when I started. So when you're working with hybrid apps it creates apps for each platform right? Well when you do that working with ionic or cordova its using the projects www folder and loads it into an Xcode project or android project and cordova just tells it how to do that. So at the root its Xcode binary being told to build an ionic project without you having to open xcode itself, when you do `ionic emulate ios` thats opening up the emulator in Xcode that you would use in an ionic project.

Comment: (2/2) For instance lets say you wanna add the facebook login to your ionic app, when you do `cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"` its going into the xcode project and editing the plist file to make it work for ios without you having to have knowledge of xcode. Does that help/make sense?

Comment: Thanks. I opened Xcode, verified availability of upgrades, and installed ios emulator, previously not present. Nothing has changed, ionic behaves exactly as before (that is, does nothing and doesn't produce error logs or messages)..

Comment: I'm not sure then, if you find something on it please update. I also see this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476437/ionic-run-build-not-working).

Comment: Strange that no one is responding.. Ionic has an active and numerous community of users...

Comment: I'd suggest running `npm install ionic -g` and if its still not working  submitting the issue

Comment: Well, I did it, but the issue is the same.. Since no error messages or logs are generated, I don't know what to submit exactly..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the platform before you can build.

`cordova platform add ios`

then, assuming you have Xcode installed properly, you should be able to build.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to build an app whether iOS or Android.  You have to add the platform.

```
Ionic platform add ios

Ionic platform add android
```

And then try building.

```
Ionic build ios

Ionic build android
```