# Ionic run / build not working

Tags: ionic-framework

[when execute "ionic run android " nothing happens !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYMR5.png)

No Errors, No Messages - what happens?

Comment: click the link to show photo

Comment: Please run *ls* command?

Comment: excuse me what what do you mean run /s ?

Comment: To show all the files in your project?

Comment: Muhsin, please explain further. Should he type `hostname$ ionic run /s` at the command prompt? If so, it's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, dropping my version of Node to 4.2.1 fixed it.

See: [Ionic run does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493015/ionic-run-does-nothing)

Comment: nvm (node version manager) works great for having multiple node versions on your dev box

Answer (score 1):

I thing the steps below can help, at least you can get a better log, to solve your problem:

1. Make sure you added a platform to your project

   $ ionic platform add android
2. Once you have a platform try to run using cordova

   $ cd {YOUR_PROJECT_DIR}/platforms/android/cordova
   $./run

Comment: thanks my friend this commend is work and run Cordova in my device but i need execute ionic run android.

Comment: Are you using node 5.0? if you do, try to downgrade to 4.2.1
Font: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33496921

Comment: For getting the updated build, after adding the platform then copy the contents from "www" folder from your project then past on "{your project}/platforms/android/assets/www" folder. Make sure replace all files other than folder "cordova-js-src" and files "cordova.js", "cordova_plugins.js".

then try to run using cordova

cd {YOUR_PROJECT_DIR}/platforms/android/cordova  [run/build]

Answer (score 1):

i just got in same kind..!
so,just check setup with `ionic info` command

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 
Node Version: v5.4.0
```

i just upgrade cordova version to `5.4.1`

this setup,worked for me..!

Comment: I removed (sudo npm uninstall -g cordova) and installed the latest version of Cordova (sudo npm install -g cordova), now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

**fix is here** (FOR WINDOWS ONLY)

I am facing the same problem of Build then i finally found out the solution.

**SOLUTION**
So You must have the Android Api 23 in order for this command to work.
Error of Daemon process will be solve after installing the Api 23 and extra 
build tools and run command 
COMMAND : cordova build android --release
I am sure this fix would help you to solve the problem.

**STEPS**
1. First check the version of android through this COMMAND:
   cordova platform help 
2. Run the build command after installing the Api 23 and extra build tools.
3. If Even this not work then Try add the variable in the 
 Environment variables > System variables > 
 add _JAVA_OPTIONS and value = -Xmx512M

Then Run cordova build android --release

BUT FIRSTLY SET UP THE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES 
[Environment Variable setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5InU.png)
[android API 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLI0J.png)

**COPY FROM HERE** 
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:-

1. **USER VARIABLES**
   **PATH** 
   C:\Ruby23\bin;C:\Users\kumar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRo
   ot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
2. **SYSTEM VARIABLES** 
   **ADD NAME AND VALUE** 
   2.1  **_JAVA_OPTIONS**   -Xmx512M 
   2.2  **ANDROID_HOME**    C:\ANDROID_SDK 
   2.3  **PATH** -> 
   C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs;C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0\bin;C:\ANDROID_SDK\tools;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;