# Ionic run does nothing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

While executing `ionic run android --device --verbose`, there is nothing happens. It logs the below message and nothing happens. ionic compile works though.

```
ConfigXml.setConfigXml path~to~my~project resetContent=true, errorWhenNotFound=false
```

ionic info yields the below information

- Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
- Ionic Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
- ios-sim version: 5.0.2
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v5.0.0
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.0.1 Build version 7A1001

Anyone has any idea what happens here?

Comment: Do you have installed the android sdk?

Comment: can try..[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34744422/4302328)

Comment: did you try to use cordova run android?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try to uninstall nodejs v5.0.0 & install nodejs v4.2.1
I was facing the same problem but in Windows 8. It just showing no error and nothing happens. Reverting nodejs version do the trick for me.

Good Luck!

Comment: As you suggested, I used the dependable 4.2.1 version and it did the trick. Now everything is working fine. Thanks @gracetay!

Comment: Do you know if this was ever raised as a bug with cordova/ionic?

Comment: I'ts working for me. i changed my node version using **nvm use 4.1.2** and then **ionic build android** work fine. 
Thanks @Grace Tay

Comment: Bro, you saved my day. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I also downgrade my node...

My system information:

- Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
- Gulp version: CLI version 3.8.11
- Gulp local: Local version 3.9.0
- Ionic Version: 1.1.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
- ios-deploy version: 1.7.0
- ios-sim version: 3.0.0
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Node Version: v5.0.0
- Xcode version: Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b

You only have to:

`brew unlink node`

`brew install homebrew/versions/node012  --without-npm`

I don't want brew to install npm package, that is why I use `--without-npm`

Answer (score 0):

i have some problem the reason from Node Version downgrade to 4 Version.

Answer (score 0):

please check compiled api is updated in your sdk manager.

Answer (score -1):

I thing the steps below can help to solve your problem:

Make sure you added a platform to your project

```
ionic platform add android
```

Once you added the platform. then copy the contents from "www" folder then past on "platforms/android/assets/www" folder.
Make sure replace all files other than folder "cordova-js-src" and files "cordova.js", "cordova_plugins.js".

then try to run using cordova

```
cd {YOUR_PROJECT_DIR}/platforms/android/cordova  [run/build]
```